# Creating vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have what I think is a trivial problem in R that I would be most grateful for some assistance with:

I am trying to select a large number of variables (>1000) from a dataframe. The variables are grouped in bundles together

I have a vector containing the start position of the variables eg. c(74, 240, 5678, 20000). 
I also have a vector containing the end positions e.g. c(80, 267, 5679, 20200). 
I am unsure of how to generate from these a vector that I could use to select the desired variables: e.g. c(74:80, 240:267, 5678:5679, 20000:20200).

I would be most grateful for any advice

Thanks

Rob

Comment: paste(c(74, 240, 5678, 20000),c(80, 267, 5679, 20200), sep = ":")

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to get the sequence of index between corresponding elements of the first `vector` ('v1') and second `vector`, `unlist` and subset the columns of the dataset

```
df1[unlist(Map(`:`, v1, v2))]
```